# React destructuring: What is the meaning of this syntax?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I was looking at react-transition-group library and I came across this syntax which I've never seen before(line 1). What does it mean?

PS: I know normal destructuring of props or state; but in this case there seems to be an assignment of the prop to the 'inProp'... Thanks in advance

```
const Fade = ({ in: inProp }) => (
  <Transition in={inProp} timeout={duration}>
    {(state) => (
      <div style={{
        ...defaultStyle,
        ...transitionStyles[state]
      }}>
        I'm a fade Transition!
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
);
```

link to code: https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition

Comment: Give this page a good read regarding renaming a variable for a destructured argument to a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this type annotation working in React code without TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

The prop 'in' is being renamed to 'inProp' for the context of the function.  This is a feature of prop destructuring.