# Are these two types of updater functions for setState in React equal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setstate

I've recently learned about [updater functions](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1) for `setState` in React.

And now I've seen this concept used in two different ways. Let's say we have a state object like this:

```
interface State {
  readonly expanded: boolean;
  readonly slugs: string[];
}

state: State = { expanded: false, slugs: [] }
```

I have seen updater functions used like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded }));
```

And like this:

```
this.setState(({ expanded }) => ({ expanded: !expanded }));
```

I've tried this out myself to see if there is a difference between using the two, but I couldn't find one (besides the amount of characters ). My intuition just tells me that the first way might be more safe because the second way `state` (in this case `slugs`) might be overwritten?

**Edit:** This questions has been flagged as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript), but it is inherently different, because I was wondering about the functionalities of `setState` and not about how TypeScript's type annotation works. I merely provided the TypeScript types for clarity. I'm sorry this question caused confusion. English is not my main language and I didn't know how to express this more clearly. Luckily someone understood and answered the question perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is this type annotation working in React code without TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript)

Comment: Also, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699006/prevent-this-state-to-be-used-with-setstate/52699118#52699118) for further help.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I believe type declaration here is used just to demonstrate inner structure of `state`.

Comment: @skyboyer OP is not confused with `state` but the use of different syntax and where destructuring helps to understand.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar yes, and he is asking whether functional and return-an-object version of `setState` have any difference in this context.

Comment: ah, yes,  but to answer both results the same, understanding about destructuring will obviously help the OP.

Comment: @J.Hesters Let us know how you think now, if you're still curious about something, then it would be our pleasure to provide answer.

Comment: It seems OP asked and run away. @J.Hesters SO is busy even in weekend. So, stay with us when you ask question. Otherwise, you'll get some downside.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Relax, I'm still here. Reading all your guys comments now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @skyboyer You were right!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into the source code, especially into [setState](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L66) and [enqueueSetState](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/144328fe81719e916b946e22660479e31561bb0b/packages/react-test-renderer/src/ReactShallowRenderer.js#L62), you can see the following piece of code:

```
if (typeof partialState === 'function') {
  partialState = partialState.call(
    pu blicInstance,
    currentState,
    publicInstance.props,
  );
}

// Null and undefined are treated as no-ops.
if (partialState === null || partialState === undefined) {
  return;
}

this._renderer._newState = {
  ...currentState,
  ...partialState,
};
```

What that means is that

```
this.setState(({ expanded }) => ({ expanded: !expanded }));
```

will end up being:

```
state = {...prevState, {expanded: !expanded}}
```

and

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded }));
```

will end being:

```
 state = {...prevState, ...{...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded}}
```

I think the second one is basically poor understanding on how the updater function works.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar The one you have mentioned does not seem to have anything to do with the question.

Comment: `state = {...prevState, {...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded}}` should be `state = {...prevState, ...{...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded}}`(it would raise syntax error otherwise)

Comment: may you please add few notes on nested objects in `state` when spread operator is actually required?

Comment: Thank you! This exactly answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

As the React' official doc [State Updates are Merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) said, React will merges the object you provide into the current state, not overwrite the whole state.

Answer (score 2):

Both the statement would result in the same behavior - updation of `expanded` value. 
If you read through the `setState` method's documentation, React expect the method to return the value that needs to be overridden. React merges the return of the method to the previous state object and does a diff. In the first clause, all the other state variables are the same, except the `expanded` and in the second clause, only `expanded` is mutated.

Answer (score 1):

To understand with the second code, you may look in attached [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript), but I found your case a little bit different. Thus, answering here.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, expanded: !prevState.expanded }));
```

Here, the use of `...prevState` is just unnecessary. It's because react's setState handles the particular state and merge other states.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ expanded: !prevState.expanded }));
```

You'll only need to use merging when you'll need to update the properties nested in the particular state. For example, if you have something like:

```
state = {
  people: {
   male: 1033,
   female: 234,
   other: 100
  }
}
```

Now, in this case you may merge people value when you only update the male count like:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ people: { ...prevState.people, male: 1045 } }))
```

Which can simply be written destructuring like:

```
this.setState(({people}) => ({ people: { ...people, male: 1045 } })
```

Comment: Awesome this enhances Sulthan's answer even more! Thank you both for your help.