# Why {source:target} when destructing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why is it `const {source:target} = obj` when destructing into new variables in Javascript and not the other way around?

I am asking since `const {target:soruce} = obj` would be more inline with...

```
const source = 'x';
const obj = {target:source};
```

...and I would make fewer mistakes. :)

Comment: `target` is an *alias* for `source` property when destructuring that way

Comment: I get that. If it were `const {source as target} = obj` like `import {source as target} from 'lib'` I would have no problems with it.

Comment: Would have to ask the committee that established the syntax. It is clearly documented though

Comment: @charlietfl I think they have established it very well. Because objects are key:value pair but  when using import statements they are not just objects.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar an alias isn't really key/value related though is it?

Comment: `const {source: target} = obj` makes much more sense considering `: target` bit is optional. Just the line `const {source} = obj` creates a `source` variable equal to `obj["source"]`. const {source:target} gives you an option to create variable name which isn't same as the key you'e targeting.

Comment: Using `as` or doing reverse would also get ugly when dealing with nested destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is interesting. So, I would like to have my opinion on this:

const { source: target } = object

1) Both sides should be equal:

```
x = x
```

2) So, both are objects:

```
{ source } = object
```

3) What if object is somehow undefined?

```
{ source } = object || { source: 'the value - not an alias' }
```

4) Key is extracted, not the value

```
const { source } // and source will hold the value
```

5) What if it were using as?

```
const { source as target } = object
// like we have
// export { source as target } from 'module'
```

It would be very much difficult for nested object keys:

```
const obj = { source: { target: 'another value' } }
const { source: { target: asValue } } = obj
```

**Can you think if we use as?**

```
const { source of target as asValue } // makes life no easier.
```

But using import/export syntax has only one consideration.

```
import { a, b, c } from 'module'
```

But not:

```
import { a, b, c } from 'module', 'another-module', 'third-module'
```

Hope, this makes sense now!

If you are in fact stuck using destructuring syntax, then you may see and follow the links provided in my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351864/how-is-this-type-annotation-working-in-react-code-without-typescript/52352059#52352059).

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense if you format it as:

```
 ({ source: target  } =
  { source: "value" });
```

especially for nested properties:

```
({ source1: { source2: target  }} =
 { source1: { source2: "value" }});
```