# Assigning a property to arrow function?

Tags: javascript

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Component = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

Component.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.object }; //what is not clear
```

It works. But why does it work? Since I'm working with JavaScript, I've never met with this before. By curiosity I've tried this:

```js
const fn = () => {};

fn.prop = true;

console.log(fn, fn(), "it seems like prop is not assigned");

//just to clarify for those who don't understand the question:

const obj = {};

obj.prop = true;

console.log(obj, "prop assigned to the object. fine.");

const secondFn = () => ({});

const objFromSecondFn = secondFn();

objFromSecondFn.prop = true;

console.log(objFromSecondFn, "prop assigned to the object. clear.");

console.log("comparison:", fn, obj, objFromSecondFn);
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. So what is the problem which this approach can solve, and what's happening under the hood?

Comment: What do you think it should do?

Comment: Your question is not clear.. Specifically your second example.

Comment: functions are objects, and so you can add properties to them just like you can with objects

Comment: (And how are the two code snippets related in any way?)

Comment: In both examples after the declaration, a property is assigned to the arrow function. That's how they are related.

Comment: "*it seems like prop is not assigned*" - it is, but it is assigned to `fn` not to `fn()`. And depending on your console implementation, it will show only the function code when logging a function, not its properties. But when you do `console.log(fn.prop, "the property itself")`, it'll be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects, but properties added to a function don't carry through to the objects they return (unless using prototypes on a constructor)

```
const fn = () => {};
fn.prop = true;
console.log(fn.prop) // is actually set, but fn().prop is not
```

In your React example, the `Component` function you created is used by library code that, without needing to run the function, reads `Component.propTypes` to enforce the types. So, you just made a callable function and some related data attached to it - creating an interface that can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

For those who needs to extend an arrow function with additional properties in Typescript:

```js
type Fn = (() => any) & { prop: boolean };
```

Answer (score -1):

It's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax introduced in es6. In which you can unpack fields from objects passed as function parameter. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) extracted from the linked docs:

```
var user = {
  id: 42,
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};

function userId({id}) {
  return id;
}

function whois({displayName, fullName: {firstName: name}}) {
  return `${displayName} is ${name}`;
}

console.log(userId(user)); // 42
console.log(whois(user));  // "jdoe is John"
```

I hope this example let you understand what's going on under the hood. And if you want to go further with your learning then I would suggest you to follow [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352059/2138752).