# How does react component get data without mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a Redux new guy, when I saw the following code I was confused by the empty mapStateToProps function as below:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
}
```

As I understood, the above function did nothing, so Redux would not give any data to the component. But in reality the component did get data. I'm totally confused, the whole code as following please:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    updateConfigs: (id, updConfigs) => {
      dispatch(updateActionConfig(id, updConfigs));
    }
  };
};

class TestConfigContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { configs } = props;
    let stateConfigs = Object.assign({}, configs);
    this.state = {
      configs: stateConfigs,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const configs = Object.assign({}, this.props.configs);
    const prevConfigs = Object.assign({}, prevProps.configs);
    if (!_.isEqual(configs, prevConfigs)) {
      let stateConfigs = Object.assign({}, configs);
      this.setState({
        configs: stateConfigs,
      });
    }
  }
   
  render() {
    const { configs: stateConfigs } = this.state;
    const { configs: propsConfigs } = this.props;
    let configs = getConfigs(stateConfigs);
    return (<DetectionConfig configs={configs} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />);
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(TestConfigContainer));
```

And what is this line mean please: `const { configs: stateConfigs } = this.state`, I never seen this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting component state not redux state. And

```
const { configs: stateConfigs } = this.state
```

`stateConfigs` is an alias to `configs`. So, now you can use `stateConfigs` instead of `configs`.

You can look into my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352059/2138752) where you can find few links to read more in detail.

Comment: I still not understand. The component is a sub-component, all of data from the outer component which invoke it. So the component should get data from this.props not this.state. There is nothing in this.state. Especially  when the outer component send data to it though componentDidUpdate.

Comment: You're constructuring with `super(props)` and the props is used in the state, and that you get.

Comment: And can you let me know which one exactly you're expecting that is getting redux state? So that I could explain further to clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check the parent of this component, i.e. where `TestConfigContainer` is rendered. You can also pass props from parent to child, because it seems that there is nothing passed through Redux, so your initial thought was right.

In the render of parent I'm sure you have something like

```
render () {
  return (
    ...
    <TestConfigContainer
      configs={...}
    />
  )
}
```

And then in your constructor in child component you are first destructuring props in this line

```
const { configs } = props;
```

Then setting these props to the local state of the component

```
let stateConfigs = Object.assign({}, configs);
this.state = {
  configs: stateConfigs,
};
```

And that's how you have it.

2. This is just [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: I also checked parent of this component, it's just a regular react super component, the react.Component nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, component `TestConfigContainer` doesn't take data from the `Redux` store (about Redux's store [read here](https://redux.js.org/api/store)).

The `config` prop must be set in the parent component and is passed to `TestConfigContainer` as its own prop. Own prop means that it is passed directly from the parent component and wasn't taken from the Redux store.

In the component's constructor (what is the constructor [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)) `configs` prop is [destructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from `props` object and is saved into components's **internal** state. So in the `render` method component is using his internal state property `configs`.

In `const { configs: stateConfigs } = this.state` the property is also [destructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as `configs` and renamed to `stateConfigs`.